# How to split large class into smaller classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm in the process of refactoring an iOS application, and one of the classes is massive. It encompasses three key functions. Checking for updates, downloading updates and processing updates.

**My question, is how would I split these off into separate classes (files) which can then be included in the core class file (TableViewController) and run the necessary functions from there?**

At present, all of the logic is in a single TableViewController class, which isn't ideal.

I'd like a structure similar to this, as I think it makes the most sense:

- **TableViewController**
- //import CheckForUpdates.h
- //import DownloadUpdates.h
- //import ProcessUpdates.h

I don't know what "type" of class the three files would need to be in order to achieve this, if that makes sense. I've got the core Class (a TableViewController), where these three additional classes will be included. What are these 3 additional classes, type wise? Are they NSObjects? Do they even need to be classes?

Sorry for the vagueness. I'm trying to abstract out the functionality for three key processes, to make the code neater and more manageable. The 'CheckForUpdates' option is likely to be used in more than one place in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Obj-C there are three basic ways to split classes:

1. You take a utility method and add it to a system class using a category. A typical example are methods that work with a `NSDate` or `NSURL`. In this case, you could add a method for checking updates to `NSURL` or `NSURLConnection` for example.
2. You can just take a group of methods and create a category on your controller 
   `TableViewController+CheckForUpdates.h`. This will not actually split the class but it will split the methods into different files.
3. Service classes - You take a functionality and you create a new class, e.g. `MyUpdater`. This can extend `NSObject` but it's possible to extend any other class. Even services can have a common ancestor if you need it.

I am not entirely sure it makes sense to split "check for updates" from "download updates". There must be some common functionality in both actions.

In this case I believe the third option would be the best but don't let the controller see 3 different classes. Ideally, the controller should see updates as one class with 3 methods - one for checking updates, one for downloading them and one for processing them. You can again split the implementation of the updater class into more classes but the controller should see a simple interface.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Separate implementations was what I was leaning towards when I mentioned separate classes. I don't want all the methods in a single location, it makes debugging very tedious. Checking for updates, in this instance, simply means querying the API and returning a count. So perhaps a category would be better for that aspect of the process, as I need to be able to check in more than one place. I could then implement the update check in the 'DownloadUpdates' aspect as required. Thanks, that's made things a lot clearer.